# Set inline style of children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I’m trying to set some inline styles to children in React. I have this that actually works, sort of:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child, i) {
      child.props.style.width = '100px'
    })
    return (
      <div>{children}</div>
    )
  }
})
```

BUT, if I try to change styles when state changes, the styles will remain the same. You can easily see this when trying something like this: (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9UvWL/)

```
var World = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { width: 0 }
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.setState({ width: 100 })
    },
    componentDidUpdate: function() {
        console.log(this.getDOMNode().innerHTML);
    },
    render: function() {
        var width
        var children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child, i) {
            width = i*this.state.width
            console.log('Setting width: '+width);
            child.props.style = {width: (i*this.state.width)+'px'}
            return child
        }, this)
        return <div>{children}</div>
    }
 })

var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <World>
                <div>1</div>
                <div>1</div>
            </World>
        )
    }
})

React.renderComponent(<Hello />, document.body);
```

It will log that width has changed, but the `props.style` is not working as expected. And using `child.setProps()` will throw "Invariant Violation: replaceProps(...): Can only update a mounted component.". Is there another "react-way" of changing inline styles to children?

Answer (score 6):

You are modifying the props object of each child directly, which bypasses parts of React's update mechanisms. We will be making this impossible soon.

In this case you want to use `cloneWithProps` inside your `World` component's render function.

```
var children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child, i) {
    width = i*this.state.width;
    console.log('Setting width: '+width);
    return React.addons.cloneWithProps(child, {style: {width: width + 'px'}})
}, this)
return <div>{children}</div>
```

`cloneWithProps` creates a new copy of the component and merges in additional props. You should use this pattern to ensure you're giving React all the hints it needs to know when to update.

Here's your example working: http://jsfiddle.net/zpao/Tc5Qd/

Answer (score 2):

Just after the "Can only update a mounted component" check, there is another [more descriptive error message](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/ddf53f97f09a652f173bc509b903ead920d92b52/src/core/ReactComponent.js#L160):

```
  invariant(
    this._mountDepth === 0,
    'replaceProps(...): You called `setProps` or `replaceProps` on a ' +
    'component with a parent. This is an anti-pattern since props will ' +
    'get reactively updated when rendered. Instead, change the owner\'s ' +
    '`render` method to pass the correct value as props to the component ' +
    'where it is created.'
  );
```

The logic comes from a different perspective than updating DOM nodes. When a DOM node needs to be changed, the way to do that normally is to get a reference to the DOM node, then set its properties. With React, instead of updating particular nodes, the render methods just return new React components with the correct properties set, then the back-end code works out which DOM nodes to update.

When something is shown wrongly in normal DOM code, it is hard to know where the problem is, since any code can update the DOM nodes.

When the code is arranged into render methods like in React, the render methods always take in `this.props` and `this.state` and return entire, fully rendered, components. Then, if something isn't rendered properly, it is always possible to look in the `render` method to find the problem, since that is the only place where that render happens. (And this works whether it is the first render or a second render, so there doesn't need to be a distinction between rendering components the first time, and updating components.)

So, the way around the problem you're describing, is to move the logic about rendering the divs into the render method which creates the divs, rather than in the render method of a different component. Something like this:

```
var World = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>{this.props.children}</div>;
    }
 });

var Hello = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { width: 0 };
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.setState({ width: 100 });
    },
    render: function() {
        var children = ["a", "b", "c"].map(function(content, i) {
            return (
                <div style={{ width: i * this.state.width }}>
                    {content}
                </div>
            );
        }, this);

        return (
            <World>
                {children}
            </World>
        )
    }
});

React.renderComponent(<Hello />, document.body);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kN4DV/2/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, you are moving the logic to the `Hello` component. I need to set state etc in the `World` component, and since it’s the "owner" of the children (?) I assumed there was a way to implement inline style changes from there without doing raw DOM traversing/modifications.

Comment: I suppose I'm thinking of the `World` component as the container for the children, but the "owner" would be the component which renders them. Unless it is specified somewhere else, the `World` component doesn't even really know what type of elements its children are. Since it is the `Hello` component which controls what the children of the `World` component are, they could even be other `World` components which wouldn't know how to handle a style property.

Comment: Yes, I suppose you are right. It’s sometimes hard to wrap your head around React’s reusable components as opposed to how jQuery used to work... I guess passing data as props into the `World` component and render the children from there would be the most logical solution.